# How to split a single JSON object into one JSON nested arrays?

Tags: javascript, json

I have JSON as show below, how can I convert it into one nested JSON arrays using JavaScript?

```
{
  "Class": [
    {
      "StudentName": [
        "Ash",
        "Win"
      ],
      "Rank": [
        "1",
        "2"
      ],
      "ID": [
        "001",
        "002"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I split it into one JSON nested arrays:

```
{
  "Class": [
    {
      "StudentName":"Ash",
      "Rank":"1",
      "ID":"001"
    },
    {
      "StudentName":"Win",
      "Rank":"2",
      "ID":"002"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Take a look at the `reduce` function of javascript and try it?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. As has already been stated, you need to show us what you've already tried, and are struggling to get working - there are many tutorials on the internet and we are not a code writing service. Please have a read of the [help] and the [ask] section in particular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this.

I have looped the items and generated the object and pushed it to class array.

```js
var data = {
  "Class": [{
    "StudentName": [
      "Ash",
      "Win"
    ],
    "Rank": [
      "1",
      "2"
    ],
    "ID": [
      "001",
      "002"
    ]
  }]
};
var result = {"Class":[]}
data.Class.forEach(function(details) {
  details.StudentName.forEach(function(det,i) {
    var rs = {
      "StudentName" : details.StudentName[i],
      "Rank" : details.Rank[i],
      "ID" : details.ID[i]
    }
    result.Class.push(rs);
  })
})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

No magic, just for loops:

```
const sourceObj = {
  "Class": [
    {
      "StudentName": [
        "Ash",
        "Win"
      ],
      "Rank": [
        "1",
        "2"
      ],
      "ID": [
        "001",
        "002"
      ]
    }
  ]
} 

const studentData = sourceObj.Class[0]    
const length = studentData["StudentName"].length

const targetObj = {
  Class: [] 
}
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  targetObj.Class.push({
    StudentName: null // Do a bare minimum yourself
  })
} 

console.log(targetObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

The json data what you get is not ideal but this would work:

```js
const testData = {
  "Class": [
    {
      "StudentName": [
        "Ash",
        "Win"
      ],
      "Rank": [
        "1",
        "2"
      ],
      "ID": [
        "001",
        "002"
      ]
    }
  ]
};

const students = testData.Class[0].StudentName.map((student, index) => {
  return {
    name: testData.Class[0].StudentName[index],
    rank: testData.Class[0].Rank[index],
    ID: testData.Class[0].ID[index],
  };
});

console.log(students);
```